# $.extend($.tablesorter.themes.jui, { Uncaught Exception :Cannot read 'themes' undefined

Tags: themes, tablesorter

I would like to sort table using tablesorter with expectation like the attached fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/saranya2020/ykn035rf/6/

Table sorts but the problem is my first column has an href link when only when +icon clicked it should expand. But after applying the below script tags for sorting,when i click up or down arrow my href automatically expands:( and during page load is get error,

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'themes' of undefined
@line: $.extend($.tablesorter.themes.jui, {

```
     <script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
     <script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
       <script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.bootstrap.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.black-ice.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.bootstrap.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/theme.jui.min.css"/>
```

Please let me know what i have missed or added wrong to avoid this problem.

Comment: It sounds like jQuery might be loaded twice on your page. The first instance contains tablesorter, and the second is trying to initialize tablesorter.

Comment: @Mottie: Many thanks for highlighting. Issue got resolved. Jui themes was initialized twice.

Comment: @Mottie: Could you please help me out how to avoid auto expansion of one of my column during sorting. In my table first column has +icon which only on clicking it expands and shows up few data. But now after applying sorting as per https://jsfiddle.net/saranya2020/ykn035rf/7/  when i do sorting my column auto expands and table looks wierd.

Comment: Please update the demo with your collapsible code to make it easier to troubleshoot

Comment: @Mottie: Please find the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/saranya2020/kf7vdgnq/57/ with normal expand and collapse. With normal html the display:none works fine. But when i include tablesorter this style is not recogonizing and always displays irrespective of condition. Please help me how to sort this

Comment: I can't tell if you only want one row to show hide, or each row to have its own hidden row. In the first scenario, add a separate `<tbody>` with the row, and in the second scenario, add a `tablesorter-childRow` class to the attached row ([demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows.html)).

Comment: @Mottie: You are genious! It works as explained in demo:)